#  accumulate all floats

Tags: java, arrays, image, graphics, floating-point

My logic is to accumulate all floats check if each pixel contain brightness in my unique brightness array[b]. Although im having problems dealing with floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I'm wondering if a `HashMap<Float, Integer>` would work for you.  The key (Float) would be the unique brightness values from the pixels, and the value (Integer) would be the cumulative count of pixels with that brightness.

```
HashMap<Float, Integer> histogram = new HashMap<Float, Integer>();
for (int ip = 0; ip < IMAGE_PIXELS; ip++) {
  float brightness = // get the brightness for this pixel
  Integer count = histogram.get(brightness);
  if (count == null) {
    count = 1;
  }
  else {
    count++;
  }
  map.put(brightness, count);
}
```